# Parsing .txt file in C

Tags: c, parsing

i am trying to parse through a .txt file in C. This is what i have so far

```
void parser()
{
FILE * rooms;
char * theString;
char * theToken;

char a[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];

rooms = fopen("assets/rooms.txt", "r");

if(rooms == NULL)
{
    printf("error opening file\n");
}
while(fgets(a, ROOM_STRING_LENGTH, rooms) != NULL)
{

    theString = malloc((sizeof(char)*(strlen(a)+1)));
    strcpy(theString, a);
    theToken = strtok(theString, " ");
    while (theToken != NULL)
    {
        printf("the next token: %s\n", theToken);
        theToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
        if(theToken[0] == 'd')
        {
            doorParser(theToken);       
        }

        else if(theToken[0] == 'g' || theToken[0] == 'm' || theToken[0] == 'p' || theToken[0] == 'h')
        {
             iconParser(theToken);
        }
    }
    if(theToken == NULL)
    {

    }

}
free(theString);
fclose(rooms);
}
void iconParser(char * theToken)
{
int k;
int item;
char posX;
char posY;
while(k <= (strlen(theToken)))
{
    switch(theToken[k])
    {
        case 'g':
        item = 1;
        posY = theToken[1];
        posX = theToken[3];
        printf("the item: %d, the y position: %c, the x position: %c\n", item, posY, posX);
        break;

        case 'm':
        item = 2;
        posY = theToken[1];
        posX = theToken[3];
        break;

        case 'p':
        item = 3;
        posY = theToken[1];
        posX = theToken[3];
        break;

        case 'h':
        item = 4;
        posY = theToken[1];
        posX = theToken[3];
        break;
    }
    k++;
}
}


void doorParser(char * theToken)
{
int side;
char place;
switch(theToken[1])
{
    case 'e':
    {
        side = 1;
        place = theToken[2];
        printf("the side: %d, the place: %c\n", side, place);
        break;
    }
    case 'w':
    {
        side = 2;
        place = theToken[2];
        break;
    }
    case 's':
    {
        side = 3;
        place = theToken[2];
        break;
    }
    case 'n':
    {
        side = 4;
        place = theToken[2];
        break;
    }
    default:
    {

    } 
} 
}
```

This is my .txt file:

```
12X6 de8 dw3 ds5 g8,7 m3,4 p2,2 h2,2
12X6 de8 dw3 ds5 g8,7 m3,4 p2,2 h2,4
12X6 de8 dw3 ds5 g8,7 m3,4 p2,2 h2,6
12X6 de8 dw3 ds5 g8,7 m3,4 p2,2 h2,10
12X6 de8 dw3 ds5 g8,7 m3,4 p2,2 h2,12
12X6 de8 dw3 ds5 g8,7 m3,4 p2,2 h2,14
```

The problem i am having right now, is that after it runs through one line or and then of the .txt file then i get a segmentation fault, Also i am wondering how i would go about converting a certain value of a string(that is a char) into an int value

Comment: What exactly are you trying to parse? A sequence of numbers, C++, XML?

Comment: I am trying to parse through the "12X6 de8 dw3 ds5 g8,7 m3,4 p2,2 h2,2", but all 6 lines of it, and im doing this in C

Comment: Learn about `for()` loops (and forget about `strtok()`, since it is rarely a solution)

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, the structure of your loop doesn't make any sense:

```
while (theToken != NULL)
{
    printf("the next token: %s\n", theToken);
    theToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if(theToken[0] == 'd')  <<< This is dereferencing NULL after last token!
```

You are checking that `theToken` is not `NULL` with the `while` condition, then you get the next token and use it immediately (by trying to look up its 0'th character) even if it is `NULL`.

The idiomatic way to use `strtok` is

```
for (tok = strtok(str, " "); tok; tok = strtok(NULL, " "))
{
   // Process the token here.
```

Comment: Sorry, i dont understand what you mean by "This is dereferencing NULL after last token!"

Comment: @destroted The `while` loop condition tests `theToken` for `NULL` and finds it is not. Then `strtok` discovers the last token has already been read, so returns `NULL`, assigning this value to `theToken`.  Then `theToken[0]` dereferences the `NULL` value and causes a segmentation fault.  Just replace your broken loop with the `for` loop above, and you will be close to a working program.

Answer (score 0):

For the second part - converting string into int - you could google for atoi function implementation. For example http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/write-your-own-atoi/
int atoi(char * str) - does exactly this it converts "1998" to 1998

Also it looks like in this case:

```
while(fgets(a, ROOM_STRING_LENGTH, rooms) != NULL)
{
   while((c=fgetc(rooms))!='\n')
   {
     roomString[i] = c;
     i++;
   }
   ...etc
```

you end up missing the first line (and all other odd lines) beacuse fgets reads the first line (and you don't use this result), then "while((c=fgetc(rooms))!='\n')" reading already the second line here...

So, instead I think what you would need to do is to parse "a" that you read with "fgets(a, ROOM_STRING_LENGTH, rooms)". I might be wrong, but I think "strlen(a)" would give you actual length of your line - not the size of the buffer. So you can just start parsing "a" instead of copying everything into roomString

Oooh and I probably see a potential reason for the Seg fault - in the loop

```
while((c=fgetc(rooms))!='\n')
{
    roomString[i] = c;
    i++;
}
```

"i" increases and you never "flush" it, there should be i=0 before every such loop, other wise your "i" keep increasing from with every iteration of bigger "while(fgets(a, ROOM_STRING_LENGTH, rooms) != NULL)" loop - that's where you can get out of bounds of your "char roomString[ROOM_STRING_LENGTH];" buffer ...

As Gene suggested in the comment, you are trying access theToken[0] element even if ti's NULL in your most inner while loop, try replacing your code:

```
theToken = strtok(theString, " ");
while (theToken != NULL)
{
    printf("the next token: %s\n", theToken);
    theToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
    if(theToken[0] == 'd')
    {
        doorParser(theToken);       
    }

    else if(theToken[0] == 'g' || theToken[0] == 'm' || theToken[0] == 'p' || theToken[0] == 'h')
    {
         iconParser(theToken);
    }
}
if(theToken == NULL)
{

}
```

with the following one:

```
theToken = strtok(theString, " ");
while (theToken != NULL)
{
    printf("the next token: %s\n", theToken);
    if(theToken[0] == 'd')
    {
        doorParser(theToken);       
    }

    else if(theToken[0] == 'g' || theToken[0] == 'm' || theToken[0] == 'p' || theToken[0] == 'h')
    {
         iconParser(theToken);
    }
    /* invoking strtok here is "safe" because you check if't NULL right after in the while loop condition */
    theToken = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
if(theToken == NULL)
{
   printf("string is over no more tokens! next line ...");
}
```

Comment: What if im trying to change a certain element of a string into an int, and not the entire thing

Comment: like in one of your functions if you have "char place; place=TheToken[2]; int place_int = atoi(place);". So you'd need to parse out the number first, and then atoi it

Comment: I did what you suggested, but im still getting a seg fault, Its starting from the beginning now but not going to the next line, i have updated the code to what you suggested