# Retrieve text from txt in c

Tags: c

So i have this txt file that i want to get for my app in c, i have to get the numbers in between the () symbols how do i achieve this.

```
(2)
(3,3)
(5,4)
(3)
```

So far my code goes as follow:

```
char[] readFile(){
    FILE  *fileToRead;
    fileToRead = open ("coordinates.txt", "r");

    int coodinate[2];

    Movimento movements; // this is where I put the coordinates

    int i=0;
    do{
        fgets(coordinate[0], "%d", fileToRead);
        fgets(coordinate[1], "%d", fileToRead);
    }while (feof(fileToRead) == 0);

    fclose(fileToRead);
    return movements;
}
```

Comment: Read the docs and think twice, what do you expect from this ...`coordinate, 30 ...`, with the definition of this `int coodinate[2]`? Read 29  `char`s (bytes) into 2 `int`s (4, 8 or 16 bytes, depending on the platform's bit width)?

Comment: you are right i put there wrong i mean to put in coordinate[0] the first value and if there is a second put in coordinate[1] and then put all of the values in an array, already edited my initial comment

Comment: Trial and error programming leads nowhere but to depressions, at least in C.

Comment: **Read** the docs, push up the compiler's warning-level to the maximum, fix your code until no more warnings are issued, be happy.

Comment: but still don't know how to retrieve only the number without the () symbols

Comment: This `fgets(coordinate[0], "%d", fileToRead);` is nonsense.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html

Comment: You might like to have a look here for answers to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22392334/694576

Comment: Not directly related to your question: it's `fopen` and not `open`, you should check if `fopen` returns NULL (this will happen if the file does not exist), and display an error message. And then please edit your question and tell us what `Movimento` is.

Comment: What C runtime functions are you allowed to use? Or are you only allowed to parse each string using character pointers? Are you allowed to use `atoi`? Are you allowed to use `sscanf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your confusing `fopen` with `open` and `fscanf` with `fgets`.
Read your file line by line using `fgets` and then parse each line and get your coordinate. You can use isdigit() for that.
You can have something similar to :

```
FILE  *fileToRead;
char s[100] = "";
int coordinate[2] = {0};
int i=0, j = 0;

if((fileToRead = fopen ("t.txt", "r")))
{
    while(fgets(s, 100, fileToRead))
    {
        puts(s);
        for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
        {
            if(isdigit(s[i]))
            {
                coordinate[j] = s[i] - '0';
                j++;
            }
        }
        j = 0;
        printf("%d %d\n", coordinate[0], coordinate[1]);
    }
}

fclose(fileToRead);
```